# Django: get and use multiple results, by using return HttpResponse( , , , ,) from a form

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I tried searching a lot. But i couldn't find an appropriate answer. So i am asking here. So please kindly help me, tell me if i am wrong or using wrong approach. Suggest me a better approach and pls tell me my mistake.

Can i get multiple values by using........

`return HttpResponse(text1, text2, text3)`

```
result = text1+ text2+ .......
return HttpResponse(result) #(without using concatination)
```

here is the code

```
def post_form(request):
    return render(request, 'post.html')

def postresult(request):
    if 'fname' in request.POST:
        message = 'Welcome : %s' % request.POST['fname']
        message2 = 'Book %s' % request.POST['book']
        message3 = 'Description of book : %s' % request.POST['desc']
        message4 = 'Book %s' % request.POST['book']
#       message5 = 'liked or unlikd article: %s ' % request.POST['like']

#       result = message + message2 + message3 + message4 + message5

        return HttpResponse(message, message2, message3, message4)

    else:
        message = 'You submitted an empty form.'

    return HttpResponse(message)
```

Comment: What do you want to *do* with the results?

Comment: First of all thank you for editing.
Secondly, as i told, I am a newbie. I just wanted to make a form and then retrieve the content from it(using request.GET) and show it on next page. Just experimenting with code to see the possibilities.
kindly pls help me in achieving what i want to achieve...:)

Comment: The HttpResponse is the page that is shown to the user. You can put whatever you like in it. It needs to be a string, but you can build up the string any way you like: concatenation, rendering a template, whatever.

Comment: So what to do if i want to display the form content after it is filled...? in and organized way......

because by using concatenation i m getting unorganized output....

Comment: And pls tell me if can i return multiple values from ****return HttpResponse (message1, message2, message 3....))
and then display it on next page

Comment: This is why you use a template to render a web page. Come on, all this is very well explained [in the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial04/).

Comment: ahaaan........well, thankyou :)
but my main question was Displaying the Multiple values using return HttpResponse.....but u r right i should use templates to get much more organized output....Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You can send as many parameters you want. Simply follow these steps:

```
import json

def post_form(request):
    data_details = {'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2', 'key3' : 'value3'}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data_details))
```

You need to convert it into `json`

Comment: Actually i have no idea about json...(as i told i am a newbie)
i just want to retrieve data from the  form.....can u tell my how to do that.....
i mean retrieving complete form when we click on submit button...
(i just know about request.GET[])

Comment: Since you are posting the data, you will get the data in `request.POST` rather than `request.GET`